# Константы на Java

Tags: java

Хочется узнать механизм реализации констант, так как тут отсутствует предопределенное слово.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static final int MY_CONST_1 = 25;
private static final dobule MY_CONST_2 = 2.3;
```

Comment: Все-таки, как правильно было описано выше, идентификаторы констант, в соответствии с Java Code Conventions, пишутся капсом.

Comment: все же правильнее сдесь. Имена можно и поправить, а вот константа обязана обьявляться static

Comment: Согласен. Сначала не обратил внимание.

Answer (score 5):

Все литералы и величины которые вы используются ложатся в пул констант класса. Если вы хотите что-то зафиксировать, то используете ключевое слово final.

```
public final int MY_CONST = 777;
```

или ссылка на объект

```
public final Object MY_OBJ = new Object();
```

но имейте в виду, что final действует только на саму ссылку, но не действует внутри

```
public final AtomicInteger V = new AtomicInteger();

...
V.set(777);
```

то же самое с массивом: вы не сможете переопределить ссылку на массив, но значения могут изменяться

```
 public final int[] MY_ARRAY = new int[1];
```

Comment: а почему без static?